# Clear all KML layers before applying new kml layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm just starting an awesome new project but I'm having issues with something that should be simple.

I am trying to clear all the KML layers before applying a new one via ajax.

https://jsfiddle.net/fkbxdaLc/2/

Is this how you clear the map?

```
  ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  Google = new google.maps.LatLng(41.875696, -87.624207);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: Google
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://portfolio.amir-meshkin.com/_timeline/years/0.kml',
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    map: map
      //url: data
  });

  ctaLayer.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
    var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
    showInContentWindow(text);
  });

  function showInContentWindow(text) {
    var sidediv = document.getElementById('history');
    sidediv.innerHTML = text;
  }




  $("#years a").click(function(e) {

    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(null);
    ctaLayer.setMap(null);
    //console.log( $( this ).data('y') );

    year = $(this).data('y');
    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      map: map,
      url: 'http://portfolio.amir-meshkin.com/_timeline/years/' + year + '.kml'
        //url: data
    });



    ctaLayer.setMap(map);

    //return false;
    e.preventDefault();
  });




});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
}
#map-canvas {
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
<div id="history">histor:</div>
<div id="years">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-y="0">0</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-y="100">100</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-y="200">200</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-y="300">300</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-y="400">400</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-y="500">500</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you tried `ctaLayer.setMap(null)` before adding the new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem code:

```
        $( "#years a" ).click(function(e) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
            ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(null);
            ctaLayer.setMap(null);
            year = $( this ).data('y') ;
            var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                map: map,
                url: 'http://portfolio.amir-meshkin.com/_timeline/years/'+ year+'.kml'
            });
            ctaLayer.setMap(map);
            //return false;
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

It creates a local version of ctaLayer (which is inaccessible outside of the function in which it is created) and adds it to the map.  Remove the `var` from the declaration `var ctaLayer = ...`

Working code snippet (from an [updated version of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkbxdaLc/3/)):

```js
var ctaLayer, map;
$(document).ready(function() {

  Google = new google.maps.LatLng(41.875696, -87.624207);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: Google
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://portfolio.amir-meshkin.com/_timeline/years/0.kml',
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    map: map
  });

  ctaLayer.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
    var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
    showInContentWindow(text);
  });

  function showInContentWindow(text) {
    var sidediv = document.getElementById('history');
    sidediv.innerHTML = text;
  }




  $("#years a").click(function(e) {

    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    ctaLayer.setMap(null);
    //console.log( $( this ).data('y') );

    year = $(this).data('y');
    ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      map: map,
      url: 'http://portfolio.amir-meshkin.com/_timeline/years/' + year + '.kml'
    });

    //return false;
    e.preventDefault();
  });




});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
}
#map-canvas {
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="history">histor:</div>
<div id="years"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-y="0">0</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-y="100">100</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-y="200">200</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-y="300">300</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! As you can tell I'm new with JS. I didn't realize you're supposed to remove the var from everywhere.

Comment: Your not supposed to remove it from everywhere, you should define the variable in the scope you plan to use it in (with the `var` keyword).